# How do I escape the '{' and '}' characters in an AutoHotKey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to write a simple auto-replace script but can't find how to insert the '{}' characters.
The usual escape characters (backtick ` or backslash ) don't seem to work for curly brackets.
e.g.

```
:co:drf::$(document).ready(function(){space}`{`n`});{Left}{Left}{Left}{left}
```

gives

```
$(document).ready(function() 
);
```

rather than

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Encase your curly braces with curly braces. This prompts AutoHotkey to send the raw character.

```
{{}

{}}
```

[AutoHotkey help file](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Comment: Note: It does not work if you use the Notepad++ texteditor (with indent) and if there is an enter included, e.g. `::test::{{}{enter}{}}` results in `{\n}\t}`. Workaround: Use `{Backspace}` and `{Left}` to reformat the result.

Comment: This doesn't work inside a Send command use SendRaw instead

Comment: @MatthewLock's answer is the right answer.